# static variable not getting incremented

Tags: c++, recursion, static, g++, binary-search-tree

I was given a problem to find the **Kth** smallest element in a BST.

The function I wrote is:

```
//THE FUNCTION TAKES ROOT OF TREE AND THE VALUE OF K AS INPUT
int KthSmallestElement(Node *root, int k)
{
    static int indicator=0;
    static Node* temp_root=NULL;
    static int count=0;           //PROBLEM
    int i=0;

    if(indicator==0)
    {
        indicator=0;
        temp_root=root;
    }
    if(root)
    {
        i=KthSmallestElement(root->left,k);
        if(i!=0)
        {
            indicator=0;
            temp_root=NULL;
            count=0;
            return i;
         }

         ++count;      
         printf("count %d k %d\n",count,k);
         printf("root.data %d\n\n",root->data);

         if(count==k)
         {
            return root->data;
         }
         i=KthSmallestElement(root->right,k);
         if(i!=0)
         {
             indicator=0;
             count=0;
             temp_root=NULL;
             return i;
         }

     }
     if(temp_root==root)
     {
         indicator=0;
         count=0;
         temp_root=NULL;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The type of input I have to give is:

**input:**

```
1              //NO OF TEST CASES
11             //NO OF NODES IN THE BST
962 29 643 291 8 298 133 481 175 916 948  //VALUE OF NODES IN BST
6                //VALUE OF K
```

**output:**

```
count 1 k 6
root.data 8

count 1 k 6
root.data 29

count 1 k 6
root.data 133

count 1 k 6
root.data 175
```

And so on printing all remaining values in ascending order. Now I am really confused why the value of **count** is not getting incremented. As the control statement is reaching after crossing **count** increment operation then why is it failing to increment the value? The compiler is g++ 5.4

Comment: You have `count=0` in a few places. Do those get hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code which seems to be unintended. Set `indicator` to some value other than **0** in:

```
if(indicator==0)
{
     //indicator=0; // MISTAKE
     indicator=1     //OR SOME VALUE OTHER THAN 0
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

After this `count` will work as expected